# How to convert javabean to post param string?

Tags: java

example:

```
public class User{
    private String name;
    private String age;
    private String address;
    .... set and get methods....
}

User user = new User();
user.setName("albert");
user.setAge("22");
```

i want convert user object to this string
`name=albert&address=&age=22`
Because i use `new URL()` to post this string.

I have much other object to convert to like this string,so i want a tool method
Is any good way to do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to create a new user based on that string or do you want to create a print method for user which returns this string?

Comment: Do you mean do this in generic way for any class given or just for your User.class?

Comment: Use the head-on approach and use a StringBuilder for those 3 fields. Any other form will use reflection. Even a custom serializer will have you appending ``String``s at some point.

Comment: @ Blobonat  I want to use ·new URL()· to post this string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using reflection for any Object type:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class ObjectToPostStringbyReflection {


    public String getPostParamString(Object o) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException{
        Class<? extends Object> clazz = o.getClass();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(Field f : clazz.getDeclaredFields()){
            f.setAccessible(true);
            if(!sb.toString().isEmpty()){
                sb.append("&");
            }
            sb.append(f.getName())
                .append("=")
                .append(f.get(o));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IllegalAccessException 
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("John");
        user.setAddress("address");
        user.setAge("18");
        ObjectToPostStringbyReflection reflector = new ObjectToPostStringbyReflection();
        System.out.println(reflector.getPostParamString(user));
    }
}
```

Result: *name=John&age=18&address=address*

Comment: You may need to think about URL-escaping the values.

Comment: @Thilo You're right.  A URLEncoder could be used for it

Answer (score 1):

You could try to find a framework which will do this for you (e.g. Spring), or you could just bite the bullet and write your own method:

```
public String toPost() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("name=")
      .append(this.name)
      .append("&address=")
      .append(this.address)
      .append("&age=")
      .append(this.age);

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: thank you.have other class like user,is a common way to convert any other object to string?

Answer (score 0):

A simple method would be this:

```
public class user{
    private String name;
    private String age;
    private String address;
    .... set and get methods....

    public String toText() {
    return "name="+this.name+"&adress="+this.adress+"&age="+this.age;
    }
}
```

If performance is important you can use [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Comment: The compiler turns this into a statement using ``StringBuilder`` anyways.

Comment: @f1sh That's true, but by directly using StringBuilder the performance is much better if you have to handle big strings. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`String postString = "name="+user.name+"&address="+user.address+"&age="+user.age;`

There are no. of ways of doing this. it could be best for you to choose!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert your object to pass by query String by Rest. It'll be impossible but if you want only a return that string when you use the toString() method.  you need to overwriting the toString method in your class.
Like that:

`@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "name="+ name + "&address=" +adress+ "&age=" +age+ 
    }`